# Code::Blocks not working with MSYS2 MinGW due to path problems

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, msys2

I installed the Code::Blocks on a Windows 10 PC using the downloaded binary [codeblocks-20.03-setup.exe](https://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries/). I adjusted the settings to point to my Msys2 MinGW compiler `C:\msys64\mingw64` and debugger `C:\msys64\usr\bin\gdb.exe`. I then created a project with the default console app in c using Code::Blocks. It can compile and run using Code::Blocks.

When I debug it it fails. Code::Blocks gives an error:

```
Cannot open file: /c/GitLab/debugging-c-code/Exercise Files/Ch02/02_01/02_02_ide/main.c
At /c/GitLab/debugging-c-code/Exercise Files/Ch02/02_01/02_02_ide/main.c:6
```

The main.c file is open in Code::Blocks. I assume the `/c/` vs `c:\` part is the problem. I have no idea how to resolve the problem for Code::Blocks.

My Setup:

```
[..]which gcc
gcc is an external : C:\msys64\usr\bin\gcc.exe

[...]gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[...]which gdb
gdb is an external : C:\msys64\usr\bin\gdb.exe

[...]gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I would avoid spaces in the paths: `/Exercise Files/`

Comment: I suspected that as well but removing the space in the directory name did not help anything...

Comment: Then you need to install the eclipse :)

Comment: Don't you have a gdb.exe at `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe`?

Comment: Don;t know if possible, but I think you should start *CodeBlocks* from the *MSYS2* environment, and load all files using the *MSYS2* paths.

Comment: @0___________ Eclipse and Visual Studio Code works fine with my setup... Code::Blocks not so much.

Comment: @ssbssa no GDB is only in usr/bin

Comment: @CristiFati Makes no difference.

Comment: so simply do not use codeblocks

Comment: No, Total Eclipse is not a solution to any problem, it is the source of problems. Don't go there... turn around

Comment: Did you do the Settings -> Compiler -> Toolchain executables, browse to parent folder then click "auto-detect"?

Comment: @Lundin Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: I suppose the gdb path might be the culprit. Try entering it manually.

Comment: `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/gdb` are not what you seek (they are Cygwin-based, and unless you know what that is, you don't need them). You need `/mingw64/bin/gcc` and `/mingw64/bin/gdb`, which can be installed from `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` and `mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb` packages respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem ... after reading the comment from HolyBlackCat. Cygwin will mangle paths because it assumes it is inside the Cygwin environment.

Updated my MSYS installation and installed GDB as part of a complete toolchain:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

Now GDB, GCC and Codeblocks are happy with each other and sharing debug information in a way that everybody understands. Now both GDB and GCC reside in `C:\msys64\mingw64`.

I originally only installed only GCC and then the other parts as I needed them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any special characters (spaces, non ASCII characters) in the paths where CodeBlocks, MinGW-w64 or your source projects are located.

More info on how you can configure CodeBlocks with MinGW-w64 can be found here: https://winlibs.com/#usage-codeblocks